# There's no about/version information or license information on the Stack Overflow App

Tags: support, bug, ios-app, licensing, stack-overflow-app

Unless I missed it, which I don't think I did, there's no 'About' or anything in the Stack Overflow iOS app. There's also no CC-BY-SA reference. (The CC-BY-SA is not present in the Stack Exchange iOS app either.)

Perhaps this was an oversight? I would expect the 'About' to be in the 'More' area.

I've reproduced this logged in and logged out.

[image: No about, version, license, etc. on Stack Overflow app]
[image: No license on Stack Exchange app]

Comment: I don't consider this a bug, sounds like it was kept out on purpose (for whatever reason).  Maybe change to [meta-tag:feature-request]?

Comment: The Android SE app's *About* page has a "TOS & Privacy Policy" section under the "Copyright 2014 - 2015, Stack Exchange, Inc." notice, itself under an "About" heading, right under that "Submit a feature request" button. There's a link to the SE ToS and privacy policy, and then attributions for OSS libraries used by the app, with their respective website link. But yeah "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required" isn't mentioned anywhere I've seen. Big deal? (honest question)

Comment: @JAL If the information is really nowhere, I think it is definitely a bug.

Comment: @duplode The app version number is in the App Store.  How is this a bug if the dev team left it out on purpose?  This isn't an oversight IMO.

Comment: @JAL I agree as far as the version number is concerned -- but not about the license.

Comment: @JAL How would you know it was intentional? And wouldn't *intentionally* leaving out information **be** the definition of an oversight?

Comment: @Draco18s I'm only saying that it's possible the about screen wasn't a priority for the v1.0 release.  The argument "we'll add it later" does not mean it's an oversight, it just means that it wasn't a priority for the dev team.  Only Brian can answer that, however.

Answer (score 1):

This will be added in SE.app 1.6.7.0 and SO.app 1.0.2.0.

Similar copy to the web will appear at the bottom of About and More in the respective apps.