# What version of the app am I using?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I was looking for a place to see the version of the app I have, so I can give it as part of bug reports, however, there is none.

I appreciate this is v 1.0, but even so, how would I know? The Stack Exchange android app has an "about" page that includes version information among other information (such as OSS libraries used, useful links and more) - it would be nice to have a similar page in the SO app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There's no about/version information or license information on the Stack Overflow App](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349289/theres-no-about-version-information-or-license-information-on-the-stack-overflo).  Although I'm not sure this should be closed as a dupe since that is for iOS and this is for Android.

Comment: I don't know how the team wants to track these, but likely as separate items per OS.

Comment: Just curious: Are there two code bases or is there a common core with a thin UI layer for each OS?

Comment: @rene the SE and SO Android app are built on a shared codebase (and part of the same project), same with the SE and SO iOS apps. On the iOS side the shared library includes UI elements, on the Android side the UI is app specific (but I'm hoping to migrate both apps to a shared library UI).

Comment: You can go to the playstore and it'll tell you there, won't it? From the app drawer, drag the icon into App Info along the top, and it'll show you there too.

Comment: @TankorSmash - it is possible, yes, but even there you need to look for it. Additionally, why the extra step?

Comment: I guess I'm just used to looking for a unified way. I'm not against having it nested into the app somewhere, I just like knowing exactly where to find it, universally.

Comment: @TankorSmash - that's kinda my point. The Stack Exchange app has such a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that it makes a lot of sense to have the version information in the app, even if it's available elsewhere in the phone settings or Play Store.

As of version 1.0.1, going live now, the app version is displayed at the end of the Settings page.

Comment: Do you mean *displayed* instead of *disabled*?

Comment: @Keiwan oops, I do. fixed! to be fair, the button is technically not enabled because clicking it doesn't do anything :P